# z-index hiding div it should be above

Tags: html, css

I have some social media icons that are being hidden when the device is scaled and it switches to .menu_scaled_wrapper. It works fine on full screen, but when the device scales it puts it below the z-index i told it to be above.

this is the live site (the page it loads is the one with the problem)
http://factormedia.co.za/

I have a feeling it has to do with the scaled menu.

Also when scaled to a width of around 1500px all the content goes above the menu even though its z-index is above.

```
.menu_scaled_wrapper{
    display:none;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    position:fixed;
    height:80px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:5000;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    box-shadow: -2px 5px 10px 0px #000;
    z-index:5000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're right,

this is occurring because Z-index only works in relation to elements and their children. What you are proposing is outside of the scope of this.

setting a z-index of 5001 to an element inside of `.mainfade` will not interact with the z-index of `.menu_scaled_wrapper` it is outside of the scope of `.mainfade`

You have two options. one set your `<aside class="mainfade">` to have these css properties:

```
aside.mainfade {
    z-index: 5001;
    position: fixed;
}
```

the `aside.mainfade` element has the same scope as .menu_scaled_wrapper element therefore the z-index will interact with it.

Or you can change the scope of menu_scaled_wrapper and place that inside your `<aside>` or vice versa, bring the `.mainfade` outside your `<aside>` so it is a sibling of `.menu_scaled_wrapper`

Comment: Also, I would set the width of your element that contains your social buttons to the exact width you need in order to prevent that element from overlapping your menu items, otherwise they will not be clickable!

Comment: Great! To make it easier I went and applied .mainfade to my contact_wrapper div as well <div class="contact_wrapper mainfade"> this way I wont have two divs stacking ontop of each other, or have to mess with z-indexs. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ive tried to do that but it gives me some weird positioning problems

Comment: Nevermind, was being silly, got it fixed, thanks for the suggestion! Id ask another question but Ill have to do that in another post sometime :) Thanks!

Comment: I'll look at it again when I get back home.  Picking up some pizza ;)

Comment: Well I actually have a question for u. Sent me a message on here so we can talk further I really like that robot image!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92913/discussion-between-factordog-and-chris-haugen).

Answer (score 1):

You should put ".menu_scaled_wrapper" class before ".mainfade" class and make z-index of ".menu_scaled_wrapper" inherit for all media options. I've tried in your website now. It works. ".mainfade" class has your social media icons so it must be above of the other layers. That's why you should exchange their positions.